# How can I know why a Docker container stopped?

Tags: docker

I have a Docker container that contains a JVM process.  When the process ends the container completes and stops.

While thankfully rare, my JVM can go legs-up suddenly with a hard-failure, e.g. `OutOfMemoryError`.  When this happens my container just stops, like a normal JVM exit.

I can have distributed logging, etc., for normal JVM logging, but in this hard-fail case I want to know the JVM's dying words, which are typically uttered on stderr.

Is there a way to know why my container stopped, look around in logs, stderr, or something along these lines?

Comment: What do you see in `docker logs` for the stopped container? Have you tried subscribing to events? The `docker` daemon exposes an API: https://docs.docker.com/reference/api/docker_remote_api_v1.16/

Comment: The container is gone, ie its not there when I do docker ps, so I dont know how to get logs on it.  I'll check into the events api.  I have monitoring so I do know the jvm died... I just dont know those last messages output to stderr, which are not logged (in the case of OOM, the logger may not even work)

Comment: You can run the docker logs [ContainerName] or [ContainerID] command even on stopped containers. You can see them with docker ps -a

Comment: Can you please mark the answer as accepted?

Answer (score 60):

You can run the `docker logs [ContainerName]` or `docker logs  [ContainerID]` command even on stopped containers. You can see them with `docker ps -a`.

Source: [the comment of Usman Ismail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27950024/how-can-i-know-why-docker-container-stopped#comment44363435_27950024) above: this is just a way to convert his comment into a proper answer.

Comment: What if my `docker logs [ContainerName]` returns nothing?